# ExtJS Memory Leak IE

Tags: internet-explorer, memory, extjs, memory-management, grid

I am facing this serious memory leak issue in IE (not sure about other browsers). I am creating a simple grid with a store and I am taking care of the auto-destroy concept but still on each RUN/REFRESH of this fiddle the memory is going up and never coming back.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a6v

What exactly needs to change in this easy fiddle to fix this problem. I request you to please help me understand the problem by fixing the fiddle here. I read hundreds of theoretical pages but couldn't understand correctly. Please fix the fiddle. I will be grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your fiddle does allocate more memory whenever you click "Run fiddle", but not if you just click "Run fiddle" once and then work with the application.

The latter is what should usually be done inside an Ext application: it is loaded once into a browser tab, and then you can work inside it, without bigger memory leaks. The browser would, upon closing the tab, kill the process and all the memory would be free again.

The problem here is that the fiddle, upon clicking "Run fiddle", does not destroy the old fiddle content before starting anew (and loading a new copy of ExtJS!). This is because the fiddle is intended for testing, and if tests go wrong, the state of the inner frame may be undefined (e.g. JavaScript errors). Trying to correctly destroy the contents before redoing it may result in the new fiddle not being executed at all.

While you can report your findings to the Sencha Fiddle team, I personally would just move on. If you find a memory leak inside Ext, which exhibits during a single execution of your fiddle, you should report it to the Sencha ExtJS team in the official forum.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the help. I changed my fiddle to follow what you said (run the fiddle once) - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a7v (still the memory keeps on going up)

Comment: I can't see what you are doing wrong. Also, I have not yet found a similar memory leak in Chrome (it's running fine for some minutes already). Please take your fiddle to the official sencha forum, Section ["ExtJS6: Bug"](https://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?134-Ext-6-Bugs).